# Cannot mock .... The profiler must be enabled to mock, arrange or execute the specified target

Tags: unit-testing, telerik, justmock

I have the following in a test (my first ever JustMock test, I might add)...

```
        var template = Mock.Create<MessageType>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => template.Subject)
            .Returns("This template has Zero tokens.");

        Mock.Arrange(() => template.Body)
            .Returns("This template has {{number}} of {{tokens}}.");
```

The class being Mocked looks like this ...

```
public class MessageType : BaseBusinessEntity
{
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int DigestsToBeIncludedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid MessageReference { get; set; }

    public int MessageTypeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PredefinedRecipients { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to run the test I get ...

> Error Message: Test method
>   Genesis.Service.Implementation.Tests.DigestFixture.ShouldCorrectlyExtractTemplateTokens
>   threw exception:  Telerik.JustMock.Core.ElevatedMockingException:
>   Cannot mock 'System.String get_Subject()'. The profiler must be
>   enabled to mock, arrange or execute the specified target. Stacktrace: 
>   at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.ThrowElevatedMockingException(MemberInfo
>   member)  at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.CheckMethodInterceptorAvailable(IMatcher
>   instanceMatcher, MethodBase method)  at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.AddArrange(IMethodMock
>   methodMock)  at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.Arrange[TMethodMock](Expression
>   expr, Func`1 methodMockFactory)  at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__6()  at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.GuardInternal[T](Func`1
>   guardedAction)  at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.Arrange[TResult](Expression`1
>   expression)  at
>   Genesis.Service.Implementation.Tests.DigestFixture.ShouldCorrectlyExtractTemplateTokens()
>   in
>   c:\Genesis\Development\Genesis.Service.Implementation.Tests\DigestFixture.cs:line
>   46

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure you have enabled the profiler from the menu.

While using Visual Studio for writing your tests you will notice the Telerik menu and the JustMock menu-item in it. Once there, you have to check if JustMock is enabled(“Enable JustMock” should be grey, see the example bellow).

[image]